# Download .txt file from another server into local (ASP MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

I have successfully download file from my local into my local in ASP MVC.

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Download", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
    <button class="btn btn-primary"  >Download</button>

}
```

**controller**

```
public ActionResult Download()
        {
            string file = @"C:\Users\Xin\Desktop\test.txt";
            string contentType = "text/plain";
            return File(file, contentType, Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
```

What I want to ask is, how to do it if the file is not in my local, but it is on different server? let say server name called **VUP-1** and the path on the server is **C:\Users\Xin\Documents\test.txt**

Answer (score 0):

You are going to download files from Server where you have kept files.

You can used Server.MapPath and pass file path.

```
   public ActionResult Download()
        {
            string file = Server.MapPath("~/Files/Demo.txt");
            string contentType = "text/plain";
            return File(file, contentType, Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
```

Comment: what should I define in server.mapPath? 
I didn't see any path.

Comment: Files is folder located in Project and when i host it in IIS i will be the same path.

Comment: where should I mention the server name? in this case, the server name is VUP-1

Comment: var a = "\\\<<REMOTE_SERVER>>\\<<Folder>>\\Test.csv";
return File(a, "application/csv", "test.csv");